# How to review flagged comments?

Tags: support, comments, privileges

Is 10,000 points enough to review flagged comments? If so, how do I go about it? (I cannot find comments in the Review/Tools sections, only questions.) If 10,000 is not enough, what level is?

Comment: The reason I asked is that on a few occasions i have flagged a comment as rude or abusive, and it was as much as day later when action was taken. I thought I might help speed up the turn-around. I guess not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flagged comments are reviewed *only* by moderators. No level of reputation will give you the ability to review flagged comments.

Comment: Thank you. Reading between the lines, I take it that "moderator" is a title rather than a description. Am I correct in assuming that the title is bestowed by election?

Comment: @JiveDadson Yes, or appointed by staff in some cases. You can help with moderation once you reach certain rep levels, but you can't become a moderator via rep.

Comment: Yes. There are two types of moderators: ones elected by the community (community moderators), and ones employed by Stack Overflow (site moderators) (if I have my terminology right). You can view all current moderators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)

Comment: OK. Thanks for the answers. I wanted to help, but if the system is not set up for it, now I know.

Comment: I appreciate the gesture. Note that there are many ways to improve Stack Overflow. Aside from the usual moderation queues, we have [SOCVR](https://socvr.org) for close vote moderation, burninates and cleanups, Charcoal HQ for plagiarism detection, we've got an effort to organize tag burnination and determione priority, there's an ongoing effort to clean up the [tag:game-development] (formerly gaming) tag. There are many ways to improve the site besides reviewing comments.